# WordPress - Add a default value to get_option if it's used as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add a default value to `get_option` if it's used as a **variable** ?

The code :

```php
$my_options = get_option( 'my_options' ); // Associative Array 'my_options'.

<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: <?php 
echo esc_attr( $my_options['my_background_color_option'] ); ?>">
```

I want to avoid an `Undefined index error` or a `false return`.

Is the following correct ?

```php
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: <?php 
echo esc_attr( $my_options['my_background_color_option'] ) ? $my_options['my_background_color_option'] : '#000'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've written it, you're only catching `Undefined Index` errors. There's also a parenthesis out of place that renders it syntactically meaningless. My opinion here is a ternary operator gets ugly with that much text. This would do exactly the same thing. You can always make things more elegant once you understand them.

```
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: 
<?php
if (
  isset($my_options['my_background_color_option']) && 
  $my_options['my_background_color_option'] != FALSE
)
  {$op = $my_options['my_background_color_option'];}
else 
  {$op = '#000';}
echo esc_attr($op);
?>
">
```

Edit:

You could also use `empty` to achieve this in less words.

```
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: 
<?php
if (!empty($my_options['my_background_color_option']))
  {$op = $my_options['my_background_color_option'];}
else 
  {$op = '#000';}
echo esc_attr($op);
?>
">
```

From there your ternary looks a little better:

```
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: 
<?php
echo esc_attr((!empty($my_options['my_background_color_option']) ? $my_options['my_background_color_option'] : '#000')); 
?>
">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code explain it very well, I didn't try it yet but I know it's the correct answer because I was missing the `!empty()` part and the additional  parentheses to wrap everything into the `esc_attr()`. thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

The most readable way is probably:

```
$my_options = get_option( 'my_options' );
if (isset($my_options['my_background_color_option'])) {
    $color = $my_options['my_background_color_option'];
}
else {
    $color = '#FF0000'; //Default color
}
```

Comment: `$t = false; var_dump(isset($t));` returns true; this does not eliminate both of his error conditions.

Comment: @parttimeturtle - I see your point but I don't think that was OP meant. I think OP meant that $color should not be false. IMO you don't need anything else then isset in this case.

Comment: Aside from the fact that OP specifically asks for both, what is your code going to set `$color` to if `$my_options['my_background_color_option'] = false` and thus  `isset($my_options['my_background_color_option'])` returns `true`? You're setting it to `false`, the exact opposite of what he wanted. https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php